# Python Amateur - 'Greeting program' - 'Referenced before assignment error'

Tags: python, python-3.4

Like I said in my previous question, I'm a python amateur. I've made a couple silly mistakes. I'm attempting to make a highly simple greeting program using Python 3.4 however I have encountered an error. The error I have is:

**UnboundLocalError: local variable 'lastNameFunction' referenced before assignment**

Here's my code (I know I probably don't need to post it all, but there isn't much of it):

```
def main():
import time 
running = True
while (running):
    firstNameInput = input("What is your first name?\n")
    firstName = firstNameInput.title()
    print ("You have entered '%s' as your first name. Is this correct?"%firstName)
    time.sleep (1)
    choice = input("Enter 'Y' for Yes or 'N' for No\n")
    if(choice.upper() == "Y"):
        lastNameFunction()
    elif(choice.upper() == "N"):
        main()

    def lastNameFunction():
        lastNameInput = input("Hi %s. Please enter your last name. \n"%firstName)
        lastName = lastNameInput.title() 
if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

I'd appreciate any help and advice! Please take into consideration I am really new to this stuff. I'm also not quite sure on having a function inside of a function, but I thought it would be a fix so that the 'firstName' was available when entering the 'lastName'.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the `lastNameFunction` declaration somewhere before you call it using `lastNameFunction()`, e.g.:

```
def main():
    import time
    running = True
    while (running):
        firstNameInput = input("What is your first name?\n")
        firstName = firstNameInput.title()
        print ("You have entered '%s' as your first name. Is this correct?" % firstName)

        time.sleep (1)
        choice = input("Enter 'Y' for Yes or 'N' for No\n")

        def lastNameFunction():
            lastNameInput = input("Hi %s. Please enter your last name. \n" % firstName)
            lastName = lastNameInput.title()

        if(choice.upper() == "Y"):
            lastNameFunction()
        elif(choice.upper() == "N"):
            main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

You can also move it outside the `main` function, but you will then need to pass the `firstName` in using the function arguments:

```
def lastNameFunction(firstName):
    lastNameInput = input("Hi %s. Please enter your last name. \n" % firstName)
    lastName = lastNameInput.title()

def main():
    ...
    lastNameFunction(firstName)
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks very much, previous comments also suggested moving the `lastNameFunction()` to before the `main()` function but none explained how to pass the firstName. Voted your answer up and ticked it!

Answer (score 2):

Move your `lastNameFunction` to somewhere before the call.  Ideally, you would place this above the `main` function.

```
def lastNameFunction():
    lastNameInput = input("Hi %s. Please enter your last name. \n"%firstName)
    lastName = lastNameInput.title() 

def main():
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply, I've tried this but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: @PythonBoy69 That can't be.  It must be something different then because with that change `lastNameFunction()` _is_ defined.  You may get it for `firstName` now as that isn't defined in that function.  And maybe you meant to `return` the input from `lastNameFunction()`.

Comment: @BlackJack the error was still the same. I apologise if my terminology was not as best as it could be, I'm still learning. I have fixed the problem now though.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you called lastNameFunction() before you defined it in the while loop. Try defining the function outside the while loop.

Comment: I've tried having the `lastNameFunction()` before the `main()` function however I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The organisation of the whole program seems a little bit off.

1. Imports usually go at the top of the module.
2. Functions defined in functions are usually just for closures, which you a) don't need here and b) might be a bit advanced for your current experience level.
3. Recursive calls like your calling `main()` from within `main()` are wrong.  When you adopt that style of control flow instead of a loop, you will eventually run into limitations of recursive calls (→ RuntimeError).  You already *have* the necessary loop, so simply leaving out the `elif` branch already asks the user again for the first name.
4. `running` isn't used anywhere, so you can remove it and just use `while True:`.

I would move asking the user for ”anything” + the question if the input was correct into its own function:

```
def ask_string(prompt):
    while True:
        result = input(prompt).title()
        print("You have entered '{0}'. Is this correct?".format(result))
        choice = input("Enter 'Y' for Yes or 'N' for No\n")
        if choice.upper() == 'Y':
            return result


def main():
    first_name = ask_string('What is your first name?\n')
    last_name = ask_string(
        'Hi {0}. Please enter your last name.\n'.format(first_name)
    )
    print(first_name, last_name)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```